# FullCalendar.js: Rendering background with time labels?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am starting to use [Fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) and love the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/). However, I am stuck with the following problem:

**Rendering background with time labels?**

I have one user specifying his available times, and another user who can do a selection out of those given times. To allow [selection](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/) we need to set `rendering: 'background'` in the events array, otherwise the main event is blocking the event insert. But when using background rendering the time labels disappear:

[image]

So how can I tell Fullcalendar to keep on displaying those time labels even in background rendering mode?

I would be happy if somebody could help me out.

Comment: What is the version??

Comment: I am using the latest, currently fullcalendar-2.3.1

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29831332/1066234

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding time labels to background events doesn't come "out of the box" but it's easy enough to do with the [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) callback.

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view ){
    if(event.rendering === "background"){
        // Just add some text or html to the event element.
        element.append( event.start.format('HH:mm') + " - " + 
                       event.end.format('HH:mm'));
    }
},
```

You can of course add a span or two if you want better formatting.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/rho79s7w/11/) with it working (Using the same base code as your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827705/))

Comment: if I append a link here, it will render correctly, but upon a click, fullcalendar will try to create new event there even when `Event.overlap == false`

Comment: @ptica, Add a mousedown event listener to the link and prevent propagation. like so: http://jsfiddle.net/rho79s7w/22/