# FullCalendar.js: Event callbacks not firing for added events that get resized/clicked/dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

After adding an event and then changing it again, nothing happens, `// * no callback`. I even used `fullCalendar('refetchEvents')` still no luck. Am I missing something? Here is the code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek'
        },
        defaultDate: '2015-04-20',
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        lang: 'de',
        columnFormat: 'dddd D.M.',
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotDuration: '00:30:00', // default is 30 min
        minTime: '12:00:00',
        // maxTime: '23:00:00',
        contentHeight: 600,
        events: [
            {
                title: '',
                start: '2014-09-01T18:00:00',
                end: '2014-09-01T20:00:00',
                dow: [1], // repeat same weekday
                rendering: 'background', 
                color: '#6BA5C2'
            },
            {
                title: '',
                start: '2014-09-02T20:00:00',
                end: '2014-09-02T22:00:00',
                dow: [2], // repeat same weekday
                rendering: 'background', 
                color: '#6BA5C2'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event',
                start: '2015-04-24 13:00:00',
                end: '2015-04-24 14:00:00',
                color: '#F77'
            },
        ],
        // * no callback
        viewDisplay: function (element) {
            alert(element);
        },

        // adding an event
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
            var title = prompt('Deine E-Mail:');
            var eventData;
            if(title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    color: '#00AA00',
                    editable: true,
                    eventDurationEditable: true,
                    // * no callback
                    eventResizeStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                        alert('end');
                    },
                    // * no callback
                    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        alert('clicked');
                    },
                    // * no callback
                    eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                        alert('dropped');
                    },
                    // * no callback
                    eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                        alert(event.title + ' end is now ' + event.end.format());
                    },
                };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick = true
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                // not helping either
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

    });
```

Visible proof:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those callbacks are not properties of the events. They are top level fullcalendar options. Each section of the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) represents one FC top level option. Some options can also be specific to certain events, but they are mentioned as such in the docs. If you look at [event object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) you see that there is no `eventResize` property, for example.

So the fix is to just move the callbacks to the top level:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    /*...other options*/
    eventResizeStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
        alert('end');
    },
    // * no callback
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        alert('clicked');
    },
    // * no callback
    eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
        alert('dropped');
    },
    // * no callback
    eventResize: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
        alert(event.title + ' end is now ' + event.end.format());
    },
    events: [{
        title: '',
    /*... etc*/
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/rho79s7w/10/) with it working.

Comment: ... and i thought it is impossible ;-) Thanks for your wonderful help.