# FullCalendar.js: Preventing selections other than on background events?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How do I prevent the user from selecting non-colored areas (background events). He should only be able to select the blue-colored areas.

[image]

Comment: This question was part of another question before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29824886/1066234 On request it became a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until [this](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2475) request that I made a bit ago is finished, the best solution is this:

Use the following function to check if an event is "inside" of a background event.

```
var isValidEvent = function(start,end){
    return $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
        return (event.rendering === "background" && //Add more conditions here if you only want to check against certain events
                (start.isAfter(event.start) || start.isSame(event.start,'minute')) &&
                (end.isBefore(event.end) || end.isSame(event.end,'minute')));
    }).length > 0;
};
```

In every event creation or modification callback, use the function.

```
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    if(isValidEvent(start,end)){ //only add it if it's valid
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
            start: start,
            end: end,
        } ]);
    }        
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
},
eventDrop: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
    if(!isValidEvent(event.start,event.end)){
        revertFunc();
    }
},
eventResize: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
    if(!isValidEvent(event.start,event.end)){
        revertFunc();
    }
},
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8auggxcm/8/) of the result.

Comment: OMG, Thank you very much!!! you saved my night, it works just fine!

Comment: @ElSinus there's a better way now. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventAllow/